# Status bar style doesn't change after I override the variable?

Tags: ios, swift

I added the following code into my UITableViewController class:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

But after I re-run the app, nothing change, the status bar is still dark:

Output:
[image: Error: status bar still dark style]

ProjectNavigator:
[image: Project Navigator]

Interface Builder:
[image: Interface Builder]

Code in RestaurantTableViewController:
[image]

I want it be white color, what should I add?

Comment: Nice question, although, text would be preferred over images where possible ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call

```
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Then the status bar style will be updated

Also, in info.plist you should set

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

Edit:

I think your `UITableViewController` is not rootViewController. If the above solution doesn't work then try setting `preferredStatusBarStyle` for your rootViewController. `UINavigationController` looks like a root controller based on your screenshot

Comment: Thanks for your kind and detailed answer. But I don't know where should I add the `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`, so I added it in the `override func viewDidLoad()`, and it didn't work...

Comment: But I don't know which one is the rootViewController? Would it be the Navigation Controller? The first controller appears after open the app is the `RestaurantTableViewController`, as the first picture I provided. Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Well... if you open your storyboard then you'll see an arrow that points to an initial controller. I think it is navigation controller. Is it?

Comment: I have a feeling that setting status bar from code is not a good solution for you. You can simply set status bar style in project tab... Setting status bar from code is used when you change status bar during application usage multiple times

Comment: Yes it is the initial controller. And I've created a class `NavigationController` for it and add the code follow your "also...", now it works. Thank you!!!

Comment: @user7813604 please, keep in mind. If you change root view controller or present some other controller modally. The new controller class should also have preferredStatusBarStyle

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do it like this **(  application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent ) in AppDelegate-:**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            windowLayout()
            application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            return true
        }

        func windowLayout()
        {
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            let statusBarView = UIView()
            statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 194/255, green: 31/255, blue: 31/255, alpha: 1)
            window?.addSubview(statusBarView)
            window?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            window?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: statusBarView)
            window?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(20)]", views: statusBarView)
           // UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
            //UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),forBarMatrics: .default)
        }


extension UIView
{

    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format:String,views:UIView...)
    {
        var allViews = [String:UIView]()
        for data in 0...views.count-1
        {
            let key = "v\(data)"
            allViews[key] = views[data]
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: allViews))

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to know how to set status bar style for each child controller:

1. Make sure `<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
   <true/>` is set up in your *info.plist*.
2. Make sure that you've written a controller class for the root controller(the entry point controller), which I didn't create one when I was writing my question post, as you can see in the pictures in my question.
3. Add the following in the root controller class (you just created):

   ```
   override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
       return .lightContent
   }

   override var childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
       return self.topViewController
   }
   ```

   I choose `.lightContent` as what I need, but you could change it to `.default` as you want.
4. Now for each specific view controller class, in my case are *RestaurantTableViewController* and *RestaurantDetailViewController*, you could add:

   ```
   override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
       return .theStyleYouLike
   }
   ```

   .theStyleYouLike could be `.default` or `.lightContent`.